# How interoperable are JQuery and Microsoft's AJAX UpdatePanel?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-ajax

I maintain a legacy ASP.NET custom control component that implements a menu using CSS and the appropriate application of jQuery. The customer has recently been asking us to implement AJAX versions of the user interface.

When I try writing a simple web page with the jQuery menu and then put a `<asp:UpdatePanel>` element on the page, I do not get the expected goodness of AJAX. Instead, the entire page flickers as IE reloads the page in response to the request.

Removing the menu control from the page makes the updatePanel code work as expected, so it's obviously some interaction between the jQuery and UpdatePanel components.

Am I being optimistic in assuming that jQuery and UpdatePanel will work together? Should I perhaps abandon UpdatePanel; if so, what is a good option for an ASP.NET-centric codebase?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally, I would do 1 or the other.

I have found that using jQuery/javascript inside an UpdatePanel is more hassel than it is worth as you always need to output the jQuery/javascript using the ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript or the ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock.

Comment: Looks like we're going to drop the UpdatePanel approach and instead implement a service with JSON for use with jQuery.